# How can I configure express to serve a single home page for many different paths?

Tags: node.js, express

This is what I have in mind:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  // server the public folder again here
});

app.get('/bar/:id', (req, res) => {
  // server the public folder again here
});
```

I'm trying to deploy a react app that uses routing. The problem is, I need to point all user-facing paths (so, /about, /contact, etc. but not /assets/images/icon.png) back to the homepage, because the react app uses react-router, and once the app is built for production and served as a static site, going to mysite.com/about gives a 404, where it wouldn't have before building.

Comment: Are you looking for `app.get('*", ...`? Put that at the end to catch everything and serve your `index.html`.

Comment: That seems to work in terms of capturing all paths that the static delivery doesn't, but then how do I deliver the static page again in that case? I can't just send the index.html file because it wont be linked to all the css/js/assets, right?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out `express.static("./path/to/site")` *can* be the *only* argument to `app.use()`, *or it can be the second argument*.

Instead of using `app.get()`, I need to use `app.use()` for these other paths.

To capture **all** paths that weren't handled by default by the static site, I could have something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

To be more specific as in the question, I could have something like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/foo', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/bar/:id', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In that case, paths that aren't handled automatically by the static site and aren't listed afterwards will result in a 404.